# Array Objects are not being modified. Only the first element is being changed continuously.

Tags: java, arrays, object

For some reason when I try to modify the elements in my array with a for loop and a while loop it only modifies the first element the way I want it to. It seems like the rest of the elements are only going through one iteration then stopping. Do you guys see anything wrong with my code below or would you need more information? I know my code fomatting sucks but I couldn't allign it correctly on here as well as I wanted.

```
   public void race()
   {
   createRunners();

   double miles = 0.0;
   for(int i = 0; i < runners.length; i++)
   {

        runners[i].run(MILE_INCREMENT, FUEL_INCREMENT, FUEL_DECREMENT);

        miles += MILE_INCREMENT;

        while(miles < DISTANCE && !runners[i].bonked())
        {
            runners[i].run(MILE_INCREMENT, FUEL_INCREMENT, FUEL_DECREMENT);
             System.out.println(runners[i]);
             miles += MILE_INCREMENT;

             if(miles < DISTANCE)
             {
                 System.out.println("*** Runner Bonked ***");

             }
              else
             {
                 System.out.println("Congratulations! Here's your medal and 26.2"
                     + " bumper sticker.");

             }
            }
          }
        }
      }
```

Comment: Your inner while loop increments miles until `miles >= DISTANCE`. Thereafter any iterations of your outer for loop will skip the while loop because miles is never reset.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

miles is being incremented but you never reset it for each runner, so your while loop is only executed for the first runner.

Comment: Thanks,How would I go about resetting it for each runner though?

Comment: @user3061879 Set miles to zero at the beginning of the for loops.

Comment: Thanks so much. It works like a charm. One last thing, I am trying to figure out how remove any Runner that bonks from going through the loop again. I am having a problem where it is saying the same runner has bonked much after the first time he has bonked out of the race. I would just like the program to remove that runner from the loop cycle so it does not keep telling me it Bonked every loop afterward.

Comment: @user3061879 - if this worked please accept my answer.  If you want to not run the loops but keep the RunnerObjects in your array then add two methods.  One for setBonked and one for isBonked().  Perform and if check at the beginning and only continue if isBonked is false.

Answer (score 0):

look at condition of your while loop ... `miles < DISTANCE` and then inside you do `miles += MILE_INCREMENT`, your miles become greater or equal to distance, so you never get into while again for you all other iterations of `for` loop

Comment: Thanks, How would I go about resetting miles for each runner though? Would having an 'if statement' that says when miles == 26.2 || runners.bonked then reset miles accumulator to 0? What confuses me is, does the accumulator for miles work independently for each new runner or am i using the same one for all of the runners?